# How to add a link on an image using play framework and scala

Tags: html, scala, playframework

Using **play framework and scala** how to use static  **image as a link** (using js or html code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You store images in /public/images folder You can use this in view file:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/image.jpg")"></a>
```

This will produce /assets/images/image.jpg URL for source img as You map public folder to /assets/*file in routes file:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```